# Eclipse Spaces & Tabs

Tags: eclipse, formatting, tabs, spaces

I like to display 4 spaces as tab in eclipse, with an actual width on the screen of 2 spaces.

When I save the file, I'd like to have 4 spaces (represented as «`.`») for a tab:

```
1st.level  
....2nd.level  
........3rd.level
```

In eclipse, I'd like to see this, where a tabstop (represented as «`->`>») should take the width of two spaces:

```
1st.level  
->2nd.level  
->->3rd.level
```

Is such a behavior possible? Does someone know any addons for that?

Thank you in advance,
~Chris

Comment: The ability to control the rendering of indentation is exactly the purpose of tabs: people use 1 tab for 1 indentation, then user can select whether to render this tabs as 2, 4 or 8 spaces. So in my opinion, this is exactly why you'd rather use tabs here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AnyEdit tools](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/index.html) sounds like what you might need.

Comment: Not exactly, as it does not provide the 'virtual tabs' that I was looking for. But a nice addon anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Open "Preferences" -> "General" -> "Editors" -> "Text Editors"

Set "Displayed tab width" to the number of spaces you would like it to insert.
Tick the Box that says "Insert spaces for tabs"

Comment: He wants to insert 4 spaces but display 2.